# regarding portable sed -e... d b or ! b?

Tags: shell, sed, posix

In [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/148280/18) edit 
[Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas) *POSIXifies* *(again)* my `sed` formatting by inserting an `-e`xpression break and another `-e`xpression statement. Now, I might just ask him why in the comments, I suppose, but it is already revision number 18 on that answer and almost all of the previous ones were already thanks to similar freebies *(if you can see deleted comments you'll know what I mean)*. Also, I *think* I'm near enough to understanding why to phrase this in a way that might be more generally useful. So here's hoping...

I generally prefer to keep my total `sed` `-e`xpressions to one if I might, but I also have a greater preference for conforming to the [spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sed.html) as near as I can, especially when the difference amounts to no more than a `<space>` and an `-e`. But I cannot do this if I do not understand *why* I should. Here's a brief rundown of the current state of my understanding:

- the `' -e '` break can portably stand in for a `sed` script `\n`ewline break in a `sed` command-line statement... *I am admittedly fuzzy about why*
- the closing brace in a `sed` `{` function `}` must be preceded by a `\n`ewline break as stated here:

  - *The `<right-brace>` shall be preceded by a `<newline>` and can be preceded or followed by `<blank>` characters.*
- a `\n`ewline break is similarly required following any use of... *`a`, `b`, `c`, `i`, `r`, `t`, `w`, or `:`.*

But I do not understand clearly how the `{` function `}` definition relates to the `!`not operator. The only mention I find of the negation operator in the spec states:

- *A function can be preceded by one or more `!` characters, in which case the function shall be applied if the addresses do not select the pattern space.*

Does this mean that use of a `!` implies `{` braces `}`? What of `$!`commands - should they likewise be separated by `' -e '` breaks? Was this what was addressed when Stéphane most recently *POSIXified* my answer?

I think it is either the `!`negation operator, or it is the `b`ranch statement he addresses in his edit - or possibly it is both at once - but I do not know and should like to. If it is *only* the `b`ranch statement, then *I believe* a `d` would do in its place and eliminate the need for the `' -e '` break, but I'd rather be certain before hazarding a thrice *POSIXified* answer. Can you help?

*I did risk it [after all](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/148280/19), but not with any great certainty...*

Comment: With `b;n;:b`, you're branching to the label called `";n;:b"` in historical and POSIX seds (and GNU sed is not in that regards).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - I get the `:` part - you drove that home months ago. But I don't fully understand why the second `sed` command was similarly *POSIXified*.

Comment: Well because `b;h;n;G;P;D` branches to the `;h;n;G;P;D` label. What do you mean?

Comment: In any case, the POSIX spec for `sed` is very unclear to me. I've requested clarifications a few times in the past, but I don't think it was updated as a result. A good test is to try with the heirloom toolchest (Solaris one, derived from the original and which the POSIX spec is largely based on).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - oh! And so the `!` is not involved at all? I mean what I asked - how does the `!` relate to a function and/or breaks required due to the `}`? Does it at all?hmmm.... any chance you could put something to that effect in an answer?

Comment: TBH, the questions in the OP are a bit too chaotic for me, but to explain things in a nutshell for `sed` learners: simply memorize `-e` as to be *mandatory* if, for instance, you want to do *multiple* replacements using regex, e. g. `sed -e 's/foo/bar/' -e 's/foo/baz/g'`. Mandatory means, "mandatory unless you want to do something really stupid" (like pipe a couple `sed` statements in a chain when there is no reason to do so; always gives me the shivers when I see this)

Comment: @syntaxerror - i dont believe that is the case at all. if you read the spec youll find that `s///`ubstitutions are spec'd to accept chaining with a *;* . it gets blurry around commands that must be delimited with a newline and how `-e` can stand in in that case - at least it does for me. ive yet to stumble on a `sed` that doesnt interpret them pretty interchangeably though.

Comment: Great point! So it's just a habit of mine to use `-e` then (still better than this stupid piping after all, no? ;)). But ... um ... of course you're right. I confess I always keep forgetting that you can use the `;` as a separator even between different `s///` regex statements. I'm just not used to it. Heck knows why.

Comment: @syntaxerror - yes, in most cases it is preferable. sometimes though, a little parallelism is a benefit. still, i do generally prefer a single out per loop iteration and passing output wholly for each in a straight line as much as i can. there are some other cases when a single `sed` simply will not do though - particularly when it comes to line counting. you need fresh input for fresh counts  following edits - and you need another `sed` - or else some algorithm which otherwise handles it.

Comment: @syntaxerror - actually, thinking twice, maybe `s///`ubs are not so clear cut as all that. For example: `s///w file` should need a newline or `-e` following it, and you need the same when `s///;t`esting a substitution as well, i suppose.

Comment: Trust me, often THEY ARE! Thanks to your excellent "brain refresher", I've now done a *very* overdue update on an old answer of mine on SF, one of which I love to call one of my "rep cornucopiae": [this one here](http://serverfault.com/questions/244944/linux-ata-errors-translating-to-a-device-name). Now if you please compare to the old `-e`-concatenated `sed` lines and now! That's worlds apart, and has given a readability boost by at least 50 percent.

Comment: @syntaxerror - I like it, but you should know that you don't need the `;` before a newline - a newline is fine. Honestly, you *could* do without the `-e` and all entirely and just write a file like `#!/bin/sed` with each command on a newline - or those that don't require such delimiters instead delimited with `;`. The ones that *do* require newlines are usually the ones that take arbitrary input - `:`label names and commands that refer to them like `b` or `t` or closing `}` curlies for functions, or `r`ead and `w`rite which take filename args. They all portably need to be followed by `\n`.

Comment: oh and `a` `i` and `c` which all accept any kind of input up to next newline.

Comment: You're really a human hints pool! Dang, you're right, works without this `;` stuff indeed. OK, to my excuse I just thought it's better to be safe than sorry. ;-) But many thanks, we're getting there. :p BUT OTOH, fiddling with this stuff in a trial-and-error fashion will usually spawn zillions of unrelated, highly-confusing error messages and warnings, so this is why I'd commonly like to avoid that at all costs.

Comment: @syntaxerror - I have a few complicated examples strewn about if you're interested. [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/167050/52934) is one from a month or two ago. And [here's another from yesterday](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171336/52934) - that one coordinates a few `sed` in something like an eval chain on a file.

Comment: TY, cool stuff! Got them bookmarked. Gonna delve myself into those the next days for sure. BTW, please do no longer feel addressed when I say "`sed` learners". You definitely are no learner (LOL), more like a pro asking other uber-pros like  Stéphane to squeeze out the very last quirks that remain. ;) *grin*

Comment: @syntaxerror - there is no offense taken here. i *am* a learner - its why im here. there is always more to learn. i am pretty good with `sed` though - but the topics covered in this question ive pretty much come to terms with since i asked it.

Answer (score 3):

So it's high-time this question had an answer, and, though I eventually intuitively worked out the *how* to do this correctly in pretty much every case some time ago, I only very recently managed to fairly concrete that understanding with the text in the standard. It's actually stated there fairly simply - I just stupidly overlooked it many times, I guess.

The relevant portions of the text are all found under the heading...

- [Editing Commands in `sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sed.html):

  - The argument *text* shall consist of one or more lines. Each embedded `\n`ewline in the text shall be preceded by a `\`backslash. Other backslashes in text shall be removed, and the following character shall be treated literally.
  - The `r` and `w` command verbs, and the `w` flag to the `s` command, take an optional *rfile* (or *wfile*) parameter, separated from the command verb letter or flag by one or more `<blank>s`; implementations may allow zero separation as an extension.
  - Command verbs other than `{`, `a`, `b`, `c`, `i`, `r`, `t`, `w`, `:`, and `#` can be followed by a `;`semicolon, optional `<blank>s`, and another command verb. However, when the `s` command verb is used with the `w` flag, following it with another command in this manner produces undefined results.

...in...

- Options: *Multiple `-e` and `-f` options may be specified. All commands shall be added to the script in the order specified, regardless of their origin.*

  - `-e`  *script* - Add the editing commands specified by the *script* option-argument to the end of the *script* of editing commands. The *script* option-argument shall have the same properties as the *script* operand, described in the *OPERANDS* section.
  - `-f`  *script_file* - Add the editing commands in the file *script_file* to the end of the script.

And last in...

- Operands:

  - *script* - A string to be used as the *script* of editing commands. The application shall not present a *script* that violates the restrictions of a text file except that the final character need not be a `\n`ewline.

So, when you take it altogether, it makes sense that any command which is optionally followed by an arbitrary parameter without a predefined delimiter *(as opposed to `s d sub d repl d flag` for example)* should delimit at an unescaped `\n`ewline.

It is arguable that the `;` *is* a predefined delimiter but in that case using the `;` for any of `[aic]` commands would necessitate that a separate parser be included in the implementation specifically for those three commands - separate, that is, from the parser used for `[:brw]`, for example. Or else the implementation would have to require that `;` *also* be backslash escaped within the *text* parameter and it only grows more complicated from there on.

If *I* were writing a `sed` which I desired to be both compliant and efficient, then I would not write such a separate parser, I expect - except that maybe `[aic]` should gen a syntax error if not immediately followed by a `\n`ewline. But that is a simple tokenization problem - the end delimiter case is generally the more problematic one. I would just write it so:

```
sed -e w\ file\\ -e one -e '...;and more commands'
```

...and...

```
sed -e a\\ -e appended\\ -e text -e '...;and more commands'
```

...would behave very similarly, in that the first would create and write to a file named:

```
file
one
```

...and the second would append a block of text to the current line on output like...

```
appended
text
```

...because both would share the same parsing code for the parameter.

And regarding the `{ ... }` and `$!` issue - well, I was way off there. A single command preceded by an address is *not* a function but rather it is just an addressed command. Almost *all* commands - including `{` *function definition* `}` are specified to accept `/one/` or `/one/,/two/` addresses - with the exception of `#`*comment* and `:`*label definition*. And an address can be either a line number or a regular express and can be negated with `!`. So all of...

```
$!d
/address/s/ub/stitution/
5!y/d/c/
```

...can be followed by a `;` and more commands according to standard, but if more commands are required for a single address, and that address should not be reevaluated following the execution of each command, then a `{` function `}` should be used like:

```
/address/{ s//replace addressed pattern/
           s/do other conditional/substitutions/
           s/in the same context/without/
           s/reevaluating/address/
}
```

...where `{` cannot be followed on the same line by a closing `}` and that a closing `}` cannot occur except at the start of a line. But if a contained command should not otherwise be followed by a `\n`ewline, then it need not within the function either. So all of the above `s///`ubstitutions - and even the closing `}` brace, can be portably followed by `;` semicolons and further commands.

I keep talking about `\n`ewline delimiters but the question is instead about `-e`xpression statements, I know. But the two are really one and the same, and the key relation is that a *script* can be either a literal command-line argument or a file with either of `-[ef]`, and that both are interpreted as text files *(which are specified to end in a `\n`ewline)* but neither need actually *end* in a `\n`ewline. By this I can reasonbly *(I hope)* infer that a `\0NUL` delimited argument implies an ending `\n`ewline, and as all invocation arguments get *at least)* a `\0NUL` delimiter anyway, then either should work fine.

In fact, in practice, in every case but one where the standard specifies a `\`backslash escaped newline should be required, I have portably found...

```
sed -e ... -e '...\' -e '...'
```

...to work just as well. And in every case - again, in practice - where a non-escaped `\n`ewline should be required...

```
sed -e '...' -e '...'
```

...has worked for me, too. The one exception I mention above is...

```
sed -e 's/.../...\' -e '.../'
```

...which does not work for any implementation in any of my tests. I'm fairly sure that falls back to the *text* file requirement and the fact that `s///` *comes* with a delimiter and so there is no reason a single statement should span `\0NUL` delimited arguments.

So, in conclusion, here is a short rundown of portable ways to write several kinds of `sed` commands:

For any of `[aic]`:

```
...commands;[aic]\
text embedded newline\
delimiting newline
...more;commands...
```

...or...

```
sed -e '...commands;[aic]\' -e 'text embedded newline\' -e 'delimiting newline' -e '.;.;.'
```

For any of `[:rwtb]` where the *parameter* is *optional* *(for all but `:`)* but the delimiting `\n`ewline is *not*. Note that I have never had a reason to try multiple line *label* parameters as would be used with `[:tb]`, but that `w`riting/`r`eading to multiple lines in *[rw]file* parameters is usually accepted without question by `sed`s I have tested so long as the embedded `\n`ewline is escaped w/ a `\`backslash. Still, the standard does not directly specify that *label* and *[rw]file* parameters should be parsed identically to *text* parameters and makes no mention of `\n`ewlines regarding the first two except as it delimits them.

```
...commands;[:trwb] parameter
...more;commands...
```

...or...

```
sed -e '[:trwb] parameter' -e '...'
```

...where the `<space>` above is optional for `[:tb]`.

And last...

```
...;address[!]{ ...function;commands...
};...more;commands....
```

...or...

```
sed -e '...;address[!]{ ...function;commands...' -e '};...more;commands...'
```

...where any of the aforementioned commands *(excepting `:`)* also accept at least one *address* and which can be either a `/`regexp`/` or a line number and might be negated with `!`, but if more than one command is necessary for a single evaluation of *address* then `{` function context `}` delimiting braces must be used. A function can contain even multiple `\n`ewline delimited commands, but each must be delimited within the braces as it would be otherwise.

And that's how to write portable `sed` scripts.

Comment: Why don't you accept your own answer?