# How to sed two same value without affecting the other

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have an xml file and I want to change one value on that file:

```
param name=swam_license_ports_overdraft_thresh

99

param name="strike_license_ports_overdraft_thresh"

99
```

The outcome I want is to sed the value 99 to 90 under param name=swam_license_ports_overdraft_thresh and the other value 99 under param name="strike_license_ports_overdraft_thresh" should not be changed.

Comment: I updated your question a bit. I added "not" for the second `99`, I hope you agree, otherwise, feel free to revert.

Comment: Is it always only the first occurrence you want to change, or always in the upper half, or always on line number 3? Can you maybe clarify this.

Comment: Hi @Bernhard I only want to change to value 99 to 90 on the first occurrence, and leave the rest as is.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, you want to remove only the first match, so you can do:

```
sed -e '/99/{s//XXX/;:a;n;ba}' file
```

With GNU `sed`, you can:

```
sed -e '0,/99/s//XXX/' file
```

Comment: You probabky need GNU `sed` for the first one, too.

Comment: @mikeserv: Can you explain more details?

Comment: I wish. [This is the best I could do](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148551/regarding-portable-sed-e-d-b-or-b).

Answer (score 1):

To remove the first match(preserve line)

```
awk '!x&&/99/{x++;$0=y}1' file
```

To remove the first match(dont preserve line)

```
awk '!x&&/99/{x++;next}1' file
```

To replace first match

```
awk '!x&&/99/{x++;$0="98"}1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n 'h;/match/n;G;P;//D'
```

That will delete only the first *match* in any input file. It

- overwrites `h`old space with every line
- overwrites pattern space with the next input on *match* lines
- `G`ets hold space appended to patern space
- `P`rints up to the first occurring `\n`ewline character occurring in pattern space
- `D`eletes same on *match* lines

The thing is though, that process results in *every* line following the first occurrence of *match* to also be *match* before it gets the next line. So it's always matching and never printing.

```
sed '/match/x;//x'
```

That one will replace the first occurring *match* in a file with a blank line.

- on *match* lines `sed` e`x`changes `h`old and pattern spaces
- if the new pattern space *(old pattern space)* also *matches* it e`x`changes them again
- else it leaves the first occurring *match* in the new `h`old space and prints the blank pattern space

Comment: hi thank you, I tried to do it, but i got no luck, this is how I execute it: sed -n 'h;/param name="swirec_license_ports_overdraft_thresh"/n;G;P;//D'

Comment: @Jason sed -n 'h;/swirec_license_ports_overdraft_thresh/n;G;P;//D'

Comment: Thank you sir, after I executed it, it only shows the whole content of the file, but nothing happened to the line I want to be replace

Comment: @Jason - can you post the file somewhere and give me a link to it? Or even just three of the sections you want edited and the expected output? I had a really hard time understanding the question - for which I apologize. But I really need the data so I can be sure. I'll help however I can. Could it be that another line in the file contained that content beforehand?