# Pattern Search between specific lines and print line numbers

Tags: sed, grep

I have a file of 20 lines. I want to search for a string between the lines 10 and 15 and print the string along with the line numbers of the original file.

I have tried `sed -n 10,15p file | grep -n "pattern"`

The problem with the above command is, the output line number 10 of `sed` will be line number 1 for `grep`.

Hence it is not printing the line numbers from the original file.

Comment: `sed '10,15!d;/pattern/!d;='`

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply Mikeserv, it worked as expected.

Answer (score 5):

When working w/ `sed` I typically find it easiest to consistently narrow my possible outcome. This is why I sometimes lean on the `!`negation operator. It is very often more simple to prune uninteresting input away than it is to pointedly select the interesting kind - at least, this is my opinion on the matter.

I find this method more inline with `sed`'s default behavior - which is to auto-print pattern-space at script's end. For simple things such as this it can also more easily result in a robust script - a script that does not depend on certain implementations' syntax extensions in order to operate *(as is commonly seen with `sed` `{functions}`)*.

This is why I recommended you do:

```
sed '10,15!d;/pattern/!d;=' <input
```

...which first prunes any line not within the range of lines 10 & 15, and from among those that remain prunes any line which does not match `pattern`. If you find you'd rather have the line number `sed` prints on the same line as its matched line, I would probably look to `paste` in that case. Maybe...

```
sed '10,15!d;/pattern/!d;=' <input |
paste -sd:\\n -
```

...which will just alternate replacing input `\n`ewlines with either a `:` character or another `\n`ewline.

For example:

```
seq 150 |
sed '10,50!d;/5/!d;=' |
paste -sd:\\n -
```

...prints...

```
15:15
25:25
35:35
45:45
50:50
```

Comment: what does the `=` in the end do?

Comment: @lucidbrot `=` is the `sed` command for printing line numbers

Answer (score 1):

Using [`nl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/nl.1posix):

```
nl file | sed -n '10,15{/pattern/p
}'
```

Comment: As an alternative to `nl` you can use `cat -n` to get line numbering, but that option's not available in all versions of `cat`; I guess it's a GNU extension.

Comment: @PM2Ring whereas `nl` is POSIX.

Comment: @muru - yes, it's POSIX, but your `sed` isn't. You need a `\n`ewline before any `}`. In most cases `...' -e \}` will do instead. The only case I've discovered in which I cannot rely on that to work is for a `\n`ewline in the right-hand side of a `s///`ubstitution. [I asked a question about it once](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/148551/52934), but aside from helpful hints here and there, I have mostly learned how to handle it portably via trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk` solution:

```
awk '10<=NR && NR<=15 && /pattern/ {print NR,$0}' file
```

If we must use **only** `sed`, then consider:

```
sed -n '10,15 {/pattern/ {=;p}}' file | sed 'N;s/\n/ /'
```

sed's `=` command will only print the line number on a separate line.  The second instance of `sed` above is used to combine every two lines so that the line number appears just before its line.

Comment: Thanks for providing multiple solutions for my question.