# Use sed to print selected lines within a range

Tags: sed, pattern-matching

Consider the simplified file

```
AAA
BBB
CCC1
DDD
EEE
CCC2
DDD
FFF
GGG
CCC3
HHH
```

I can pick out the range `EEE` to `FFF` with

```
sed -n '/EEE/,/FFF/p'
```

Suppose though that I want to print any line containing `C` but only within the matching range. I can pipe the result from `sed` through `grep`

```
sed -n '/EEE/,/FFF/p' | grep 'C'
```

I could also do the range and match in a little `awk` script (or `perl`, `python`, etc.). But how would I do this using just one invocation of `sed`?

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of [Pattern Search between specific lines and print line numbers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/178551/22142) if you remove the "line numbers" part. I'm sure there are better candidates out there...

Comment: @don_crissti looks that way doesn't it. But I couldn't find anything previous before asking.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a block in which you tell sed to only print when it sees C:

```
sed -n '/EEE/,/FFF/{/C/p}'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try :

```
sed '/EEE/,/FFF/!d;/C/!d'
```

Comment: I like this solution too. I haven't got my head around the idea of deleting lines I don't want (although that's perfectly reasonable in a stream editor), and actually not having the `-n` flag requiring `/p` has advantages. Thanks